# Define connections between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL tables:

```
create table dbo.Users (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),  
  Name nvarchar (120) null,
);

create table dbo.Organizations (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),  
  Name nvarchar (120) null,
);
```

What would be the best way to create tables that hold:

1. Connections between 2 Users;
2. Connections between 1 User and 1 Organization.

Should this be done with only one table?

Comment: What's the nature of the connections? Are 2 connected users related like parent/child or siblings (equal)? I'm guessing each organization might be related to 0 or more users?

Comment: Basically, each user must be able to add other users and organizations to a favorite list. So, a users favorite list and an organization favorite list. Just that.

Comment: So, it's a many to many relationship in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it is a many to many relationship in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a many to many relationship you must add an intersection table. Since you have 2 connections, you need 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FavoritUsers (
  FU_UserId int FOREIGN KEY References dbo.Users(Id), 
  FU_FavofitUserId FOREIGN KEY References dbo.Users(Id),
  PRIMARY KEY (FU_UserId , FU_FavofitUserId)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.FavoritOrganizations (
  FO_UserId int FOREIGN KEY References dbo.Users(Id), 
  FO_FavofitOrganizationId FOREIGN KEY References dbo.Organizations(Id)
  PRIMARY KEY (FO_UserId , FO_FavofitOrganizationId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to another table - e.g. OrganizationTree. This should have one column for Orga.ID and two columns USer_ID and Supervisor/Parent/Manager/whatever_id in order to hold the Connection between two persons.
Another possibility would be to extend the user table by another column (like "parent_id", "Supervisor_id" or whatever). But then you still woul Need another table for the Orga Connection.